# Theming an MVC3 ActionLink so that all links have a consistent width

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

We are using posts and gets, which out-of-the box appear as links (gets) and buttons (posts).  In an effort to provide a pleasant and consistent look to the UI, we have button themed all UI click interactions to look the same using css:

```
.minimal
{
   background: #e3e3e3;
   border: 1px solid #bbb;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   -ms-border-radius: 3px;
   -o-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #f6f6f6;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #f6f6f6;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #f6f6f6;
   color: #333;
   font: bold 12px "helvetica neue" , helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
   text-align: center;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
   text-decoration: none;
}

.minimal:hover
{
   background: #d9d9d9;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #eaeaea;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #eaeaea;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #eaeaea;
   color: #222;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.minimal:active
{
   background: #d0d0d0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #e3e3e3;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #e3e3e3;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #e3e3e3;
   color: #000;
}
```

...and used this way:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ID }, new {@class = "minimal"})
 <input type="submit" class = "minimal" value="submit" />
```

The problem is with the padding statement in .minimal, it seems that depending on the length of text contained in the ActionLink you will get a longer or shorter button.  I would use the 'width' tag but in only has effect on the posts... not on the ActionLinks.  Has anyone successfully addressed this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`width` only works on block elements. Try to add this:

```
a.minimal {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 198px; /* subtract border */
}
```

and add width to .minimal:

```
width: 200px;
```

(or style for links in general and treat the submit button in a special way)

For better cross-browser compatibility you might also need to do some trickery according to this [(old) article](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/):

```
a.minimal {
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 198px; /* subtract border */
}
```

You need to try what works for your target browsers. I tried the first (simpler) solution and it works on all current browsers and IE7 + IE8.

Comment: Setting display: inline-block; was the key.  Thanks for this, all works.

Comment: @Geoff - Note: inline-block doesn't work in IE7, if it matters.

Comment: @MystereMan It works when I put IE 9 into IE7 mode, but I don't have a real IE7 here. This is an interesting read, though: http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html

Comment: The target browser is IE9.  Works well enough in that, and that is my primary concern.  Thanks to all for the comments.